# Access on host served Angular app in Hyper-v

Tags: windows-7, networking, hyper-v

for testing purposes I want to access my Angular application -- served on port 4200 of my computer (Windows 10) -- inside my HyperV virtual computer (Windows 7).

If I enter `http://<host-ip>:4200` in IE or Chrome, I get:
*This page can't be displayed*.

Through `ping <host-ip>` I can sucessfully address the port and
thanks to @Mick I did try: `netstat -ano | find ":4200"` on my host, telling me

```
127.0.0.1:4200   0.0.0.0:4200   LISTENING
```

I tried:

- different switches (Intern / Extern)
- disabled the firewall on virtual machine

without any success.
Any ideas?

Comment: Ping cannot address a port. How are you confirming that the Angular app is running? Is it running on the host or guest? (Your last bullet point mentions disabling the guest firewall, but that doesn't have anything to do with not being able to access a host port.)

Comment: I just ment to say I can ping the IP in general, the Angular app is running on the host and I can access it there. I am not sure if it is the port, I just assumed that since it looks most likely to me that it *is* the port

Comment: Did you try `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`? By default `ng serve` does not allow connections from outside your current OS.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask more detailed information for this issue?
This Angular app is running on the Hyper-V host? And used the port 4200? 
Did you run the command "**netstat -ano | find ":4200**" "to check if the port 4200 is listening on the host?
I observed a similar thread as yours. It may cause the port used by the app is already in use. please check the following link if it helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091735/port-4200-is-already-in-use-when-running-the-ng-serve-command

Comment: **Yes**, angular is served on the host machine (Windows 10). **Yes** it runs on port 4200. **Yes** I just tested `netstat ...` on my host and it *is* indeed listening. By the way: it's no problem to access the app on the host itself, so the port seems to be alright.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but the link is no help :/